# Domain aliases in Postfix / Dovecot setup

Tags: postfix, dovecot

My mailserver is known by 3 different domains, e.g. `mail.local, mail.foo.example.com, mail.bar.example.com`. I want delivery to be the same no matter which address was chosen. Ideally I want dovecot to put `user@mail.any.of.those` into the `user` mailbox, i.e. not into `user@some.domain`.

I'm not even sure, if this is to be solved by some alias maps in postfix, or by settings in dovecot.

What I do currently is:

```
# main.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_mailbox_domains= mail.local, mail.foo.example.com, mail.bar.example.com
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1 

# master.cf
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${user} -a ${recipient}
```

But this puts mail for `user@mail.local` into `MAILDIR/user@mail.local/Maildir/new`

Answer (score 1):

As it seems `dovecot-lda` can do the trick using the `-a` argument:

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${user} -a ${user}
```